# Prevent reading PHP files

Tags: php

For better security(or for better hacker-life-difficulty) i do not trust even on my php files and my question is :

```
<?php

//how to deny any reading of .PHP files from standard PHP functions like file_get_contents?
echo file_get_contents('../../settings.php');

?>
```

As you see, the settings.php can contain site-relative passwords and should not be readed(but should be normally included by include or require)

Comment: Nobody forces you to place sensitive data in PHP files and then save then in a folder that is inside the web server document root. There are alternatives known: https://dev.to/enygma/keeping-credentials-secure-in-php-1mgo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you see, the settings.php can contain site-relative passwords and should not be readed(but should be normally included by include or require)

You can't.

You basically require that your php scripts should be able to read the configuration, and use information contained in the configuration. At the same time, they should not be able to read the configuration file and use information from it. That's impossible.

Comment: What about using .env file that are located outside of the document root? This would reduce the risk that by a simple broken e.g. Apache config php files are not executed but just transmitted and thus leaking sensitive data like passwords.

Comment: @Robert Sure. But the secrets will by default be available to anything running inside that environment via the [`getenv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function.

Comment: In such a case a modern docker based deployment strategy would enhance security as only one application would get access to the environment.

Comment: Sure. But if that application is compromised...